How can I call a Lambda function directly from a React app on Amplify without using Congito as Auth?
I have an publicly accessible app that should get some data from a Lambda function. I've provided the Amplify app with a service role (IAM) that grants access to the Lambda. However, when I call the InvokeFunction method of the AWS SDK 3.0, the error "Missing credentials" are thrown. As I haven't provided any, it makes somewhat sense..
Is it at all possible to use the service role to get access to the Lambda, or do I need to either create a function URL for the Lambda function or wrap an API Gateway API in front of it?
import { LambdaClient, InvokeCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda";

const client = new LambdaClient({ region: "eu-north-1" });

  const input = {
    FunctionName: "test",
  };

      const command = new InvokeCommand(input);
      const response = await client.send(command);
      console.log(response);


Error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Credential is missing
